# Running rails migrations in docker container sometimes results in ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container that is created for my application that has a mounted volume on my applications directory and sometimes when I run my db:setup command I get a ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError. I'm not entirely sure why this might be happening since the application runs properly in other environments. It seems like docker is either mounting my file system twice or something else weird is going on. Has anyone heard of duplicate migrations being pulled into a docker container before? Or is there some way I can debug why this is happening in my containers?